# Integral closure of lexsegment ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_d]$ where $k$ is a field and $I$ be a lexsegment ideal of $R$ and $l(I)=d$ (where $l(I)$ is analytic spread of $I$).

***Is $I$ integrally closed?***

If I is generated by elements of same degree then $I$ is Integrally closed. I do not know the answer in general.